# Generate UML model fromSpring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, uml

Is there a way to reverse engineer a Spring MVC application to UML model? Preferably using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool Magic Draw UML, which has some addons which can reverse engineer UML Model from code. I don't know how does it work in practice, or even more with Spring MVC. There is Eclipe integration also with this tool. Unfortunately, it is non-free.